# UAC warning with one file and not the other?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have two identical files. Example1.exe and example2.exe. Example2.exe was created by copying example1.exe and renaming it. When I start example2.exe, I get the UAC warning box. When I start example1.exe I get no UAC box. Again the only thing that's different about these files is the name.

Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: I don't know that we have enough information. There are various possibilities. One for example is if example1.exe were installed with an installer running with elevated rights it could have given the exe permissions that would not trip UAC but your copy would not necessarily have those permissions.

Comment: If you rename the one that triggers UAC to be named as the one that doesn't trigger it, does it get triggered?  If this is a custom-written program, perhaps someone used the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7352) against it?

Comment: You are right techie007, someone did use the application compatibility toolkit. I would mark your answer as correct if you had it as an "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Techie007's answer. If he leaves an answer himself I'd be happy to give him proper credit.

...If this is a custom-written program, perhaps someone used the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit against it?

Someone did use the toolkit.